# PC^2 equivalent compatible with Python

Tags: python

I will be running a programming competition for high school students in the near future, and was originally going to use PC^2 (Programming Contest Control System) for the automated judging of the solutions. This software is commonly used in the ACM's International Collegiate Programming Contest regionals as well as the world finals. This is an excellent system which I have used before, but one of its pitfalls is its language support (Java, C, and C++). I'm a little bit concerned, as not all high school students who may be attending will have exposure to any of these languages. However, many local high schools teach introductory programming courses in Python. Is there an equivalent system to PC^2 which has Python support?

Comment: Your best bet would be to contact the folks that do this contest directly, to see if they support Python.  Their e-mail address is one that I found in their Wiki - pc2@ecs.csus.edu.

Comment: I'm fairly certain they don't support Python. I've spoken with the individuals in charge of the Mid-Central Regional at the University of Chicago and they know for a fact PC^2 only supports the three languages I've listed. I'm looking for an alternative to PC^2 with similar features (i.e. solution submission, judging, clarifications,  and so on).

Comment: In the current version (9.5.4) Python is supported natively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some open source implementations of the online judges. 
for example ONJ http://sourceforge.net/projects/onj/

It is easy to configure and it can be made compatible to run on languages of your choice. You dont need local copies of it on every system where the students will sit, you can just run it on a server and give the students its web-link to submit their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Do it with [Sphere Online Judge](http://spoj.com), contest hosting is free of charge, many languages available.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a much better way to accomplish this. In their latest release, PC^2 added support for interpreted languages (such as Python, etc). Since PC^2 requires an executable, you need to "stub out" the compile command and simply invoke the interpreter with the script.

The full guide can be found at http://pc2.ecs.csus.edu/wiki/Interpreted_languages

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are still interested, PC^2 is very adaptable. I run a scripting contest using it and support Python, Perl, PHP and Ruby. Basically, PC^2 expects a language to compile and then run. You need to write a dinky script that pretends to compile the code and return success. Then the run script simply runs the scripting submission. Pretty easy to do.

You can visit http://acm2012.scusa.lsu.edu and look at the scripting contest info. Feel free to contact us for more info.

Answer (score -1):

It's simpler than one may think. The following is for pc2 9.2.3-2565

Add language as follows (python here as an example):

Display Name: Python
Compile Cmd Line: touch OK
Executable Filename: OK
Program Execution Command Line: python {:mainfile}

python3.3 or python3.4 will work too.

pc2 could be easier, of course, but there does not seem to be much support left at CSUS. Reseting contest would be even greater feature; the current need to clone directories for test, practice, and actual contest is very awkward. Better management of the database (like the ability to remove things) would make it into a great tool. It is alright, but it could be great.